# How to make lists dynmically in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am very new to SharePoint. The task I have been given I this:
There is a list of different tasks. When a new user is registered,  I have to choose specific tasks from the list and then assign them to the user. The user should be able to see the tasks assigned to him only. I thought of creating different lists per user and then assign tasks in that list. I am not sure if creating a new list using a workflow is possible or not. Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Task List which will have the People or Group Column for assignee, you can use CSOM approch to assign the task dynamically. If you want to understand task List please refer to - https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-manage-tasks-in-sharepoint/

Task List has OOTB view "My Task", which will show the tasks assigned to logged in user.

Comment: Can I assign fields from an existing list to a Task List? Also, when I read about Task Lists, I saw that I cannot assign multiple tasks at once to a user. Is there a solution to solve the problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you also elaborate about the CSOM approach? I could not find muh about it

Comment: Instead of list you can use task list, every task will be added as an item to TaskList. One user can have multiple tasks assigned. Only one challenge -- You cannot assign one task to multiple users, if you want to do that then create another people/group column for Secondary assignee in your task list.